# Struggling with a weird syntax error Unexpected token * error

Tags: node.js, heroku, nestjs

I've run this app many times, but in my changing something here and there to help it run on heroku instead of just on my app, i've begun to receive this error

```
...packages\backend\dist\main.js:1
import * as tslib_1 from "tslib"; SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

The weird thing is, I don't even use tslib 1 in my typescript; so it's auto-generated when building, but when I try to run the app from production, it hangs.

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions":{
     "target":"esnext",
     "moduleResolution":"node",
     "module":"esnext",
     "declaration":false,
     "noLib":false,
     "emitDecoratorMetadata":true,
     "experimentalDecorators":true,
     "sourceMap":true,
     "pretty":true,
     "allowUnreachableCode":true,
     "allowUnusedLabels":true,
     "noImplicitAny":true,
     "noImplicitReturns":false,
     "noImplicitUseStrict":false,
     "outDir":"dist/",
     "baseUrl":"src/",
     "listFiles":false,
     "importHelpers": true,
     "noEmitHelpers":true
  },
  "include":[
     "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude":[
     "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave":false
```

I believe I may have changed something important at tsconfig.json, but I don't know what! Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this works, but I just made the following changes

```
 "module":"commonjs",
 "target":"es6",
```

Again, unsure why it works, but it does...

Answer (score 2):

In fact when you are developing on server side using nodejs you have to set up your `tsconfig` with

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

To know what are the difference between `"None", "CommonJS", "AMD", "System", "UMD", "ES6", "ES2015" or "ESNext"`

I recommend you to read this article https://medium.com/computed-comparisons/commonjs-vs-amd-vs-requirejs-vs-es6-modules-2e814b114a0b